# Minor open checking and saving account

Tags: united-states, checking-account, savings-account

Is it the norm for banks to allow a minor (age 17) to open either or both types of accounts in America?

Comment: I am unsure what you asking.  Okay I know EXACTLY what you are asking but I don't know what you really want to know.  A quick search would tell you.  Are you asking about the pros/cons?  Purpose of such an account?  Looking for advanced knowledge to avoid a rip off?  This seems like a good question, but I hope you will fill it out a bit more.

Comment: Did you ask your local bank?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the norm for banks to allow minors in the United States, under 18 years of age, to open a checking or savings account. It is however the norm for banks to allow accounts to be opened by custodial account holders on the behalf of a minor of any age, even less than 1 year old.

Answer (score 1):

My bank (Wells Fargo in the US) says that accounts are available to teens ages 13-17 with an adult co-owner.  As a teen my first bank account (at a different bank) was also co-owned with my dad, so this is normal for me.